# saving Operations accidentally deletes geometry data

Tags: geoserver, wfs, openlayers-2

From time to times, the geographical coordinates of some features of my program get deleted on any update - without an obvious cause.

The layer uses `WFS  1.1.0` as protocol. The saving Operations looks approximately like this

```
     feature.attributes.Abteilung = "02";
     feature.state = OpenLayers.State.UPDATE;
     features = [feature];
     saveStrategy.save(features);
```

In the log, it looks like this:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/06/17 09:21:11 | Request: transaction
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/06/17 09:21:11 |     service = WFS
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/06/17 09:21:11 |     version = 1.1.0
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/06/17 09:21:11 |     baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/06/17 09:21:11 |     group[0] = wfs:update=net.opengis.wfs.impl.UpdateElementTypeImpl@e6f68e (filter: [ Graeber.1068 ], handle: null, inputFormat: <unset>, srsName: null, typeName: {Ahaus_neu}Graeber)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/06/17 09:21:11 |     update[0]:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/06/17 09:21:11 |         property[0]:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/06/17 09:21:11 |             name = GEOMETRYproperty[0]:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/06/17 09:21:11 |             name = ABTEILUNG
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/06/17 09:21:11 |             value = 02property[0]:
```

which I understand as: the property GEOMETRY is not set to any value.

What I want now, is either:

**To detect the cause (it happens only very seldom)**

or

**To prevent any update that sets GEOMETRY to NULL**

or:

**To make the SaveStrategy ignore the geometry and to only update the attributes**

is one of these possible and how??

Comment: No ideas so far?